# How to call name user has login

Tags: laravel

```
public function getDeletee($id)
{
    $data['data'] = DB::table('lembur_karyawan')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->delete();

    $users = DB::table('users')
    <your code??>
    ->first();

    return redirect('user/detail/'.$users->name);
}
```

(ASK) how to call user who has logged to $users?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Auth::user();
```

Instead of:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
<your code??>
->first();
```

To get the name, use `Auth::user()->name;`

More on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication).

Comment: opps, problem again Trying to get property of non-object, what wrong? any idea?

Comment: If you're getting this error when trying to `Auth::user()->name`, that means that no user was authenticated. You can check this with `if (!Auth::user()) { echo 'You're not authenticated, please login' }`

Comment: but i am not with auth, i make controller own.